# async-http-client-2.12.3 library is vulnerable

Tags: release, new-operator, asynchttpclient

I am using async-http-client-2.12.3 library but it is vulnerable and on maven repo site does not have any new release from last release. so, any update on "async-http-client" library, when will it be release new version?

when will it be release new version after v2.12.3?